# Как изменить коэффициент масштабирования при перемещение карты в yandex maps api.

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, yandex-maps-api

Как изменить коэффициент масштабирования при перемещение карты в yandex maps api. Есть следующий код:

```
destinations = {
            'Germany': [51.150443,10.453979],
            'Russia': [64.397509,100.102416],
            'Belarus': [53.902692,27.573522]
        },
        menuContainer = $('#mapMenu');
        for (var item in destinations) {
            (function (title, geoPoint) {
                $("<li><a href=\"javascrtipt:void(0)\">" + item + "</a></li>")
                    .find('a')
                    .bind('click', function () {
                        menuContainer.find('a').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
                        $(this).css('text-decoration', 'none');
                            myMap.panTo(geoPoint, { });
                        return false;
                    })
                    .end()
                    .appendTo(menuContainer);
            })(item, destinations[item])
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, вам нужно вот это:

http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/ref/reference/Map.xml#setZoom

Добавить после строки

```
myMap.panTo(geoPoint, { });
```